# Spring Controller mapping error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in spring development.
I am trying to make an helloworld application works. But the /welcome path result in a 404 page.

Here is my configuration :

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" /> 

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**SpringController.java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SpringController {
    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() 
    {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome"); 
    }
}
```

In the console output I can see :

```
INFOS: Mapped "{[/welcome],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView controller.SpringController.helloWorld()
```

But when i go to "http://localhost:8080/test/welcome" I still have a 404 error

Could you help me please?

Comment: Why /test/welcome??? ommit the test

Comment: Because my project name is test. Both url  /welcome and /test/welcome return a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely a URL matching problem in your web.xml

Please change the `<servlet-mapping>`URL patterns. Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/Spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

You will notice that the url-pattern now is only "/". This will forward any incoming request to your application to the dispatcher servlet, which will forward it to the corresponding controllers. The `<context-param>`loads your Spring-servlet.xml configuration file into your application context. Make sure the Spring-serlvet.xml file is in your WEB-INF folder.

You should also have a view called "welcome.jsp" in your WEB-INF/jsp/ folder -
 because that is what your SpringController is returning in helloWorld()